# I have some code that worked but I'm having trouble running it now

Tags: powershell

We had an intern who wrote the following code to search a shared drive for files (parts of names in an Excel file) and copy them to a folder on another shared drive. I am cutting and pasting to Powershell but it is not doing anything. I guess I'm missing some steps and may not have the Excel file in the correct folder and may not be in the correct drive/directory to start with. I would appreciate any help with explaining how this code works and what I might need to do to run it properly. Thanks. Here is the code:

```
# This script takes an Excel file as the first argument and a directory as the second argument
# It reads the values in the F column of the first sheet, except for empty cells
# It removes the first two letters from each value and appends "[A-Za-z0-9_-]*\.DWG" to form a           regex pattern
# It searches for files matching that pattern in the given directory and all subdirectories
# It prints the path of all matching files to the terminal

# Check if the arguments are valid
if ($args.Count -ne 2) {
Write-Error "Invalid number of arguments. Usage: .\match.ps1 <Excel file> <Output Directory>"
exit
}

$excelFile = $args[0]
$directory = "K:\Production Release\"
$outputDirectory = $args[1]

if (-not (Test-Path $excelFile)) {
    Write-Error "Excel file not found: $excelFile"
    exit
}

if (-not (Test-Path $directory)) {
    Write-Error "Directory not found: $directory"
    exit
}

# Create a COM object to access the Excel file
$excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open($excelFile)
$worksheet = $workbook.Worksheets.Item(1)

# Get the last row with data in the F column
$lastRow = $worksheet.Cells($worksheet.Rows.Count, 6).End(-4162).Row

# Loop through the F column values and build an array of regex patterns
$patterns = @()
for ($i = 1; $i -le $lastRow; $i++) {
    $value = $worksheet.Cells($i, 6).Value2
    if ($value) {
        # Remove the first two letters and append "[A-Za-z0-9_-]*\.DWG"
        if ($value.Length -eq 17) {
            $pattern = $value.Substring(2, 12) + "[A-Za-z0-9_-]*\.DWG"
            # Write-Output $pattern
        }
        else {
            $pattern = $value.Substring(2) + "[A-Za-z0-9_-]*\.DWG"
        }
        # Add the pattern to the array
        $patterns += $pattern
    }
}

# Close the Excel file and release the COM object
$workbook.Close()
$excel.Quit()
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($excel) | Out-Null

# Search for files matching the patterns in the directory and subdirectories
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $directory -Recurse -File

foreach ($file in $files) {
    foreach ($pattern in $patterns) {
        # Check if the file name matches the pattern
        if ($file.Name -match $pattern -and !(Test-Path -Path $outputDirectory -PathType       Leaf)) {
            # Print the file path to the terminal
            Write-Output $file.Name
            #Copy-Item $file.FullName -Destination $outputDirectory
        }
    } 
}
```

I opened Powershell. Copied the code, pasted it into the Powershell window and hit enter.

Comment: You have to invoke the file from within PowerShell given 2 arguments, *as mentioned in the comments*, the source path and the destination path for the output. Either call it accordingly, or remove the first `if` statement entirely and assign the file path to `$excelFile`  and the destination to `$outputDirectory`

Comment: "*Usage: `.\match.ps1 <Excel file> <Output Directory>`*", is the comment from the error message. So: `C:\path\tops1\match.ps1 "C:\path\To\Excel.xlsx" "k:\output\directory"`

Answer (score 1):

Please save the code in a file. Perhaps, `Get-Drawings.ps1`.

Open a PowerShell console and `Set-Location -Path 'C:\path\to\the\file'` where the Get-Drawings.ps1 file was saved.

Then use the command:

```
.\Get-Drawings.ps1 'C:\path\to\drawings.xlsx' 'C:\output\directory'
```

Comment: I was getting an error because it  did not see my K drive but I took care of that. I tried running again as noted above and it does not look like anything happened.  PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> net use k: "\\dvfs01\dvi_engineering"
The command completed successfully.

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> set-location -path 'c:\drawings'
PS C:\drawings> .\match.ps1 c:\drawings\drawings.xlsx' 'c:\drawings\drawings'
>>    The file with the drawings is c:\drawings\drawings.xlsx. I want to search all folders in k:\production release\ and copy the drawings to c;\drawings\drawings\

Comment: Does the `$outputDirectory` exist and is it a directory? `C:\drawings\drawings`

Comment: They do exist. Is there a way to trace to see where the failure is? To figure out if it is not finding files to copy, cannot find directories, etc.?

Comment: Yes, using a debugger make it easy to trace through the code. I use the Microsoft Visual Studio Code editor which includes a debugger. And, it is the right price. https://code.visualstudio.com/download

Comment: Getting closer. I just reran using: PS C:\drawings> .\match.ps1 'c:\\drawings\\drawings.xsls' 'c:\\drawings\\drawings\\' and it displayed the names of the files I'm looking to copy on the screen however they were not copied to the c:\drawings\drawings folder. The search part is working, it found the files. Just need to nail down the copy/paste part.

Comment: In the code posted in the question, the `Copy-Item` command line is commented out.

Comment: @kforan, if this answer has been correct and is the best answer (there is only one (1) at this time), then please select the check mark to indicate that to other users. That is how SO works.